# Align Media at right bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media

I want to place an image at the bottom right corner of a text and that text should take col span of 5. I have the following code and it creates a scroll bar vertically on the page.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5">
      <div class="Mymsg">Welcome to Era</div>
      <div class="msg">here you are!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="media">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="media-object" src="images/myIamge.png"/>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: what's your expected output? can you show as image?

Answer (score 0):

Please add two more classes `col-sm-7` `col-md-7` for the `media`:

```
<div class="media col-sm-7 col-md-7">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="media-object" src="images/myIamge.png"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried that and it did not work out in removing the scroll bar

Comment: @Smitha Can you please provide a working fiddle or snippet to demonstrate what you see?